# How to determine via commands or terraform the status of Azure key Vault policy, Does it have access policies or RBAC?

Tags: azure, terraform, command-line-interface

How to determine via commands or terraform the status of Azure key Vault policy, Does it have access policies or RBAC?

I want to create a condition inside module to check if KV has access polices or rbac and assign permission accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for `enableRbacAuthorization` property for your key vault when you get the details using [`az keyvault show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-show). A value of `true` means data actions are authorized using Azure RBAC.

For example, this is the output for one of the key vaults in my Azure Subscription where Azure RBAC authorization is turned on for the key vault:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kvname",
  "location": "eastus2",
  "name": "kvname",
  "properties": {
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "applicationId": null,
        "objectId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "permissions": {
          "certificates": [
            "all"
          ],
          "keys": [
            "all"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "all"
          ],
          "storage": [
            "all"
          ]
        },
        "tenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    ],
    "createMode": null,
    "enablePurgeProtection": true,
    "enableRbacAuthorization": true,
    "enableSoftDelete": true,
    "enabledForDeployment": true,
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": true,
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
    "hsmPoolResourceId": null,
    "networkAcls": null,
    "privateEndpointConnections": null,
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
    "sku": {
      "family": "A",
      "name": "standard"
    },
    "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 90,
    "tenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "vaultUri": "https://kvname.vault.azure.net/"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "rgname",
  "systemData": {
    "createdAt": "2023-06-02T05:53:35.713000+00:00",
    "createdBy": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
    "createdByType": "User",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2023-06-02T05:53:35.713000+00:00",
    "lastModifiedBy": "xxxx@xxxx.com",
    "lastModifiedByType": "User"
  },
  "tags": {},
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
}
```

For more details, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keyvault/vaults/get.